# How to get reply from the remote source using Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm implementing a simple request-reply pattern to communicate with remote source using Spring integration. i could see it can send request to the source and also the source send back the reply through Wireshark.

But i can't get reply message in my application. Once i configured my application using `outboundGateway` i could see the reply message has no EOF delimiter and since default `ouboundGateway` uses `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` it throws `TimeoutEXception` So i re-configured my application to use `ChannelAdapter` setting `ByteArrayRawSerializer` so that client can get reply.

```java
@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    connectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    connectionFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());
    connectionFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());
    connectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);

    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, poolSize);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel", outputChannel = "responseChannel", requiresReply = "true")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler requestHandler() {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    handler.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());

    return handler;
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel responseChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow responseFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(responseChannel())
        .handle(message -> {
            log.info("Reply: {}", message.getPayload());
        })
        .get();
}
```

This is my setup i expected that if i specify the `outputChannel` on `@ServiceActivator` i can get the reply in that channel but i can't.

The examples out there shows the default client and server connection but since the reply come through the port that client opened and the server only reply when client request i don't think i need a server connection in this case.

Please let me know if i misunderstood or missed something. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a streaming protocol; you need some mechanism (e.g. CRLF, LF, etc) to delimit messages within the stream. The `ByteArrayRawSerializer` uses the socket close to determine when all the data has been received. It sounds like your server is not closing the socket.

You need to determine which mechanism the server is using the delimit messages within the stream and select an appropriate deserializer; either one of the standard ones, or a custom one.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think i should use `Socket` instead since the server can't provide any delimiter soon. It is impossible to get reply if i close the connection after request to server isn't it?

Comment: You will have the same problem using a Socket - how will you know when all the data is received? Using the raw deserializer requires the server to close the socket after sending the reply, not the client.

Comment: I have the spec of message that server produce so i may use static length of byte so that i can read the message at least. I will ask my client if they can add proper delimiter thanks!

Comment: If you know the structure, you can write a custom deserializer to use in the gateway.

Answer (score 2):

See `ByteArrayRawSerializer` JavaDocs:

```
 * A byte array (de)serializer that does nothing with the payload; sends it raw.
 * Message termination for assembly purposes is signaled by the client closing the
 * connection. The serializer does not, itself, close the connection after
 * writing the bytes.
```

So, with this deserializer the "end of reply" is only initiated when you close the connection.

The `TcpSendingMessageHandler` is one-way channel adapter and it doesn't not produce any replies. With a `TcpOutboundGateway` you need to look into some other strategy for messages demarcation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs.

You may also look into a collaborating channel adapters approach: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-collaborating-adapters